# is this a void pointer? casting? what is it doing?

Tags: c, declaration, void

I am new to the C language and pointers and I am confused by this function declaration:

```
void someFunction(int (*)(const void *, const void *));
```

Can anyone explain in layman's terms what this does and how it works?

Comment: I think you have one too many `(` in the code you copied. Would you check please and edit?

Comment: ah yes, thanks for spotting that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the prototype of a function that takes:

> a pointer to a function that takes a `const void*` and a `const void*` as arguments and returns an `int`

as an argument, and returns `void`.

Answer (score 2):

It declares a function, which takes another function as its argument, and returns nothing. The other function would be declared as

```
int otherfunction( const void *, const void * );
```

and you would call somefunction() like this:

```
somefunction( otherfunction );
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a function that has a single parameter. That parameter is a pointer to a function that returns an int and takes those two void pointers to constant data parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This is the declaration of a function which takes a [function pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer) as its argument. In its most basic form, it looks like this:

```
void someFunction(argument_type);
```

Where `argument_type` is `int (*)(const void *, const void *)`, which can be described as a "pointer to a function that takes two const void * arguments, and returns an int". i.e. any function that has the following declaration:

```
int foo(const void *, const void *);
```

To illustrate by example:

```
int foo_one(const void * x, const void * y) { ... }
int foo_two(const void * x, const void * y) { ... }

void someFunction(int (*)(const void *, const void *) function_ptr)
{
    const void * x = NULL;
    const void * y = NULL;
    int result;
    result = (*function_ptr)(x, y); // calls the function that was passed in
}

int main()
{
    someFunction(foo_one);
    someFunction(foo_two);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check this](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) very helpful when dealing with complex declarations.